# .load() afeta o desempenho do site

Tags: jquery, html

Gostaria de saber duas coisas, e se possível um exemplo.

Tenho um sistema de comentários que depois que envia e grava no banco de dados e aparece sem dar refresh, praticamente igual aos comentários do *facebook*. No momento estou fazendo o retorno por `.load()` para adicionar o html com as variáveis. Isso é prejudicial? O `.load()` deixa mais lento?

Ia fazer via `.html()`, mas são diversas linhas, é grande o html do comentário (porque tem a foto, nome, data, menu, tudo no espaço do comentário) e achei que ficaria mais organizado por `.load()`, onde passo as variáveis pelo *jquery*, ele adiciona no html e depois coloca na `<div>` com o `.load()`.

Existe alguma maneira mais eficaz ou o `.load()` não deixa o sistema mais lento?

Tenho medo que quando colocar o site em funcionamento, se tiver muitos comentários, fique lento...

Comment: O load provavelmente e mais lento que o .html devido a ele fazer um parse na resposta (se o documento for text/html por exemplo) e tenta extrair e executar tags como <link> e <script> que vieram desta requisição. No entanto no seu caso acredito que o problema possa ser outro.

Comment: Mas eu consigo passar um html com 20 25 linhas pelo .html() ? eu tentei ontem e deu erro, sempre mostram exemplos pequenos...

Comment: Nao entendi, me parece que voce esta com multiplos problemas, estou certo? O que eu disse e que o load tenta fazer um parse do dados

Comment: @DiegoCamilodeBittencourt uma dica, para cada dificuldade distinta faça uma pergunta. É interessante também ver trechos do seu código onde está com essa dúvida, é difícil avaliar se esse erro que você menciona está em como tu usas essa função ou em alguma outra coisa, com o código vai ficar mais fácil a análise.

Comment: Na verdade não tenho problemas, o sistema funciona muito bem mesmo... o load funciona isso eu consegui de boa... mas dai disse que seria melhor fazer em html, os dados do banco de dados eu consigo pelo jquery no success, então poderia colocar o html e substituir os dados do user e comentário com jquery, isso também faço tranquilo. E como colocar tantas linhas de html de maneira eficaz por jquery, essa que fiquei meio em dúvida... .html() ? consegue colocar 20 25 linhas?

Comment: Diego, sim como eu ja disse, consegue sim fazer com .html tanto com .load, o que vai afetar isto e o tipo de resposta que esta sendo recebida pelo .html (acredito que esteja usando ajax). Se estiver recebendo html entao a requisição, o parse e a renderização vão ser mais lentas mesmo. Isto nao e uma coisa certa de responder, pois o problema pode variar com a resposta que esta recebendo no .html. Por isto volto a repetir amigo, o problema nao e bem com o .html mas "provavelmente" com a tua aplicação.